# Programatically Create an Excel Sheet that Auto-sizes Columns

Tags: c#, excel, converters

I am writing a C# program that takes information from a database and converts it to an Excel sheet. However, it makes the columns the same default width each time. I know once it's loaded up, you can select all and re-size in a few clicks, but I'm being asked if it's possible to do during its creation while running the C# program. This is using WinForms in Visual Studio 2008.

Thank you!

Comment: Would recommend EpPlus if you are working with Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Range.AutoFit function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofit.aspx) to make the columns fit automatically to the longest content. MSDN states:

> The expression must be a row or a range of rows, or a column or a
>   range of columns.

```
range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
range.EntireRow.AutoFit();
```

Detailed examples could be found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345396/net-c-sharp-excel-column-autofit) and in this [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6206eb77-d5c3-4819-8894-acbc44783fcd/using-autofit-on-excel-worksheets).